# Can I Invoke a nancy Module by myself

Tags: c#, .net, nancy

Let's assume I have this Nancy Module

```
public class ProductModule : NancyModule
{
    public ProductModule(IProductRepository repo)
    {
        Get["/products/list"] = _ =>
        {
            ViewBag.Categories = repo.GetAllCategories();
            return repo.GetAllProducts();
        };
    }
}
```

I am using Razor as ViewEngine and I am able to display a list of products.

Now I want to be able to execute the same request within a Windows Forms application. I know I can do something like

```
var bootstrapper = new CustomBootstrapper();
bootstrapper.Initialise();
var engine = bootstrapper.GetEngine();
var request = new Request("GET", "/products/list.xml", "http");
var context = engine.HandleRequest(request);
```

Anyway that does not fit my needs since it involves the whole http pipeline and serializes my `IQueryable`. But in my windows Forms application I already have a proper pageing support for `IQueryable<>` objects. Currently I am supposed to have some redundant code with

```
public class ProductController
{
    dynamic ViewBag = new ExpandoObject();
    public dynamic List()
    {
        ViewBag.Categories = repo.GetAllCategories();
        return repo.GetAllProducts();
    }
}
```

And I want to get rid of that and only use my nancy modules.

Basically this has to be possible somehow, since, in my razor view I have exactly what I want and have full access to the ViewBag and Model.

I already downloaded the source but have not managed to find the right buttons to push.

Any suggestings would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd recommend not doing this. You could simplify it by adding a method to your `repo`: `GetAllCategoriesAndProducts` that returns a POCO that's shared across your website and WinForms. The `ViewBag` is attached to a `NancyContext` so I don't think you can avoid the HTTP pipeline.

Comment: Well, the nancy modules (there is more than one) already exist and I still want to use the rest of the nancy logic (uri parsing, access control) without any modification. The one thing is that I need is to bypass the HTTP pipeline for IQueryable<T> objects for displaying the data in a grid that supports dynamic paging.
I really believe this will be possible with nancy, since it is build from scratch without any dependencies to system.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution within the [nancy testing framework](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Testing-your-application)

Digging deeper with test extensions

```
public class GetModelExtententionsTests
{
    private readonly Browser _browser;
    public GetModelExtententionsTests()
    {
        this._browser = new Browser(with => {
           with.Module<AModuleToTestExtensionMethodsWith>();
           with.ViewFactory<TestingViewFactory>();
        });
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Can_get_the_model_and_read_the_values()
    {
       var response = this._browser.Get("/testingViewFactory");
       var model = response.GetModel<ViewFactoryTestModel>();
       Assert.Equal("A value", model.AString);
    }
}
```

> Note: Use of these extension methods requires the use of the
>   TestingViewFactory, set on the testing Browser object. It's a wrapper
>   ViewFactory that saves the Model and then exposes it with the
>   extension method. You don't have to think too hard about that though,
>   only make sure to set the TestingViewFactory (e.g.
>   with.ViewFactory();).

So basically the solution is to implement a viewfactory that store the model before rendering the view.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not sure why the advice of @eth0 is not appropriate in your specific case, `Nancy.Testing` at least provides a way of circumventing the network stack.

```
var bootstrapper = new CustomBootstrapper();
var browser = new Browser(bootstrapper);
var result = browser.Get("/products/list.xml", with => { with.HttpRequest(); });
```

For more details see the official documentation: [Testing your application](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Testing-your-application)

Comment: That's not true. Nancy.Testing does not require a server process running but simulates a real http request. That means my model gets serialized and deserialized which is not what I need. @eth0's advice is not appropriate because eventually I want my windows forms application to utilize nancys routing (I want to bind a button click to a route `/products/12345/edit`, pass it to nancy and handle the result myself).

Comment: Thank you for clarification. You are right, my answer is about circumventing the network stack which does not solve your problem. :-( I will change the wording so others will not get confused.

Comment: Basically I need to find the exact spot after nancy executes the route and before the model gets serialized. I think replacing `bootstrapper.GetEngine();` will be a good start. As soon as I find time for it I will dig in the nancy code to figure out how to do it.